# Is it possible to specify key value in m3u8 in stead of specifying a key file?

Tags: uri, http-live-streaming, m3u8

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if it is possible to directly specify the key *value* in m3u8 in stead of specifying a key file. Hex value of the key file is `723C581D81C3316D89D3E1CB158FFF43` and VLC Player can playback the m3u8 when specifying the key file using `URI="0.key"`. I've tried `URI="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,723C581D81C3316D89D3E1CB158FFF43"` and didn't work. Not in favor of a separate key file, so if it's possible, what exactly should I put in the m3u8 as uri?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the HLS specs and what you have outlined above looks correct but I think you will find that Amy players don't actually support it.

For example an open ShakaPlayer request (at time of writing):

- https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues/2146

A similar issue with ExoPlayer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625511/334402

You may find the easiest way is actually to host the key in a separate file, even though that is not your preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using base64 encoding seems to work for some implementations at least. VLC can't read it, but hls.js works properly.

First convert your hex key into base64:

```
> echo '723C581D81C3316D89D3E1CB158FFF43' | xxd -r -p | base64
cjxYHYHDMW2J0+HLFY//Qw==
```

Then use the base64 string as the key URI in your m3u8 file:

```
URI="data:text/plain;base64,cjxYHYHDMW2J0+HLFY//Qw=="
```